# Conditional rule evaluation with FluentValidation.NET

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

What I want to achieve can be roughly summarized as a simple OR conditional.

Whilst there is support for conditional property validation on OTHER properties with Fluent Validation (When/Unless) there does not appear to be a way to support conditional rules on the same property? Or am I missing something?

Essentially I want to achieve:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).CanEitherValidateThisRule().Or.CanValidateThisRule();
```

The only alternative to this is to combine the rules in a single custom rule? 

However, this tightly couples the rule logic and realistically they are completely separate conditions that I may want to use on other objects/fields.

There was a suggestion to support this in a future version of FluentValidation.NET, does anyone know a way to achieve this with extension methods or if there is a syntax that I've missed?

**EDIT**: Found the discussion: [Fluent Validation for .NET - View Discussion](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/348513)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Chaining Validators for the Same Property](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Chaining)
Although its a dirty way to do what you want, its still worth if you are doing the validations for a small part of code.

If you want a cleaner way, then,as of now, I think creating a [custom validator class](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomValidator) is the most convenient option.

The wiki page I have linked to gives all the necessary tools to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - chaining validators is precisely what I want to achieve, however with an OR condition rather than rule().[and]rule()